# laravel @include not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I am trying to include files in my user page using blade syntax

```
@include('header')

@yield('content')

@include('footer')
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ulsz.png]

here is web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts.user');
});
```

i'm getting this error

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException View [layouts.user] not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always have to use the absolute path to a view. So in your case, this should be:

```
@include('user.layouts.header')

@yield('content')

@include('user.layouts.footer')
```

The same counts for your routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('user.layouts.user');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you should include full path from the view folder so it will look like this:

```
@include('user.layouts.header')

@include('user.layouts.footer')
```